# Camel streaming splitter for large json files

Tags: apache-camel

Does camel have support for streaming splitting of large JSON data? I know that the support is there for xml. I tried splitting large json files with jsonpathexpression. It worked fine with small files but gives OOM exception with large files.

```
JsonPathExpression jsonPathExpression = new JsonPathExpression("$.");


 from("stream:hxxp://dummy:5984/test/a123/p.txt")
                        .split(jsonPathExpression).streaming().parallelProcessing()
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                String s = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                            }
                        })});
```

Comment: can you share your route? Did you use the jsonpath expression with the spilt() method?

Comment: Yes I did provide the expression. edited the question to include code snippet.

Comment: I think you need to fill in a enhancement request at jsonpath project so we can read the JsonPath in an iterating mode (they have an internal PathTokenizer)

Comment: Did anything come of this ? i need this functionality too ... or some way to make this happen