# how to split a json array in apache camel

Tags: json, rest, split, apache-camel, jsonpath

I get a json array as input from a rest-interface, based ond apache-camel-spark. At the beginning, i want to split the json-array to process each element individual through apache camels routes. How i do this?

My test-input-json:

```
[
  {
      "document": {
        "name": "blub1",
        "type": "pdf"
      }
  },
  {
      "document": {
        "name": "blub2",
        "type": "pdf"
      }
  }
];
```

For this problem, i found some questions on stackoverflow, which describe this indirectly:
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23408904/camel-streaming-splitter-for-large-json-files), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30761293/can-i-split-compressed-files-into-json-components-in-camel-via-spring-dsl), [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39981444/apache-camel-split-jsonarray-remove-the-double-quote).

Based on the examples, i tried the following camel-routes:

```
restConfiguration().component("spark-rest").port(8080)
  .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
  .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true");

rest("/v1/users").consumes("application/json").produces("application/json")
  .post("/insert")
  .to("direct:split");

from("direct:split")
  .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
  .split(new JsonPathExpression("$..document.")).process(new Processor() {
      public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
         String s = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
         System.out.println(s);
      }
   }).to("file:outbox");
```

When i do this, i get always the following exception:

> ERROR DefaultErrorHandler            - Failed delivery for (MessageId:
>   [...] on ExchangeId: [...]). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1
>   caught: org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I didn't found the reason, whats wong with my expression? I changed it, but i always get the NullPointerException.

I downloaded the [JavaScript jsonPath library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/downloads) and tested the `$..document.` expression, which serves me an array with the two objects. I also tried it in camel, which says, that the expression was found (returns true) in the test-input-json:

```
from("direct:testExpression")
        .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        .choice()
            .when().jsonpath("$..document.", true)
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                exchange.getIn().setBody("true");
                System.out.println(payload);
                }
            })
            .to("file:outbox")
        .otherwise()
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                String payload = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                exchange.getIn().setBody("false");
                System.out.println(payload);
                }
            })
            .to("file:outbox");
```

What do i wrong, why i get the NullPointerException and how do i split the json?

Here the full Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.camel.ExpressionEvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluate(JsonPathExpression.java:95) ~[camel-jsonpath-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ExpressionAdapter.evaluate(ExpressionAdapter.java:36) ~[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.createProcessorExchangePairs(Splitter.java:113) ~[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:231) ~[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:108) ~[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) ~[camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:542) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [camel-core-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.sparkrest.CamelSparkRoute.handle(CamelSparkRoute.java:46) [camel-spark-rest-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:58) [spark-core-2.3.jar:?]
    at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:162) [spark-core-2.3.jar:?]
    at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:61) [spark-core-2.3.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpression.java:118) ~[camel-jsonpath-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at org.apache.camel.jsonpath.JsonPathExpression.evaluate(JsonPathExpression.java:88) ~[camel-jsonpath-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    ... 31 more
```

Comment: How do you start/run Camel? I suspect you dont do this properly and the json expression is not initialized with its engine and you get that NPE.

Comment: Hi @ClausIbsen, thank you for your response. Camel starts well with an embedded Jetty in camel-spark and other routes are accessable over browser, like http://localhost:8080/v1/users/list for example. For the problem i send a post request with Postman, then the route shown above is called and i get the NPE. I start Camel wit main.run() in an own Thread, if this has maybe an side effect, what do you mean?

Comment: In my pom.xml i set the artifact "camel-jsonpath". The doc says (http://camel.apache.org/jsonpath.html), this is enough?

Comment: But how do you start Camel from Jetty, eg what do you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating your jsonpath expressing similar to:

```
ExpressionBuilder.languageExpression("jsonpath","$..document.")
```

and put that in your split and try. I have had more success with jsonpath this way when doing various conditional evaluations.